# I can't find classes/attribute on matplotlib documents

Tags: python, matplotlib, figure

From the code below, all I want to know is what is the window used for?

```
plt.ion()
figManager = plt.get_current_fig_manager()
figManager.window.showMaximized()
```

I went to the matplotlib documentation, searched for `get_current_fig_manager()` and it retured `FigureManagerBase`. I then looked at `FigureMangerBase`, and there's no window attribute, methods, super class is object.

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using the `Qt5Agg` backend and look at the repr of the `figManager.window`, it is a `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5.MainWindow` object.

Digging into the MPL code, you can find it is just a wrapper object for the `QtWidgets.QMainWindow` object.  Code [found on github](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt5.py#L513):

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    closing = QtCore.Signal()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.closing.emit()
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.closeEvent(self, event)
```

It looks like it just gets tacked on as an undocumented attribute to the `FigureManagerBase` object as a way to reference the open Qt window.  This allows the user to access the Qt windows when in interactive mode without having to import Qt.

Probably should be documented.  You can always put in an issue.